# visual basic 6 combobox get selecteditem value

Tags: combobox, vb6

vb.net 2012 its works perfectly
but now iam trying to work at vb6

```
Private Sub showSelectedButton_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click 
If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "one" Then
        MsgBox("ok")
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "tow" Then
        MsgBox("no")
    End If
End Sub
```

how to selecteditem on VB6 ?

Comment: iam trying to get the selected item in combobox 
i mean i want to know what item is selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this :

```
If ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex) = "one" Then
```

or

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "one" Then
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with this -

```
Private Sub showSelectedButton_Click() 
    If ComboBox1.Text= "one" Then
        MsgBox("ok")
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text= "tow" Then
        MsgBox("no")
    End If
End Sub
```